# Trying to create site-wide Active Directory sync with Multisite

Tags: multisite, multisite-user-management

we have a multisite server running, and we've got the Active Directory Integration plugin running. It works great individually, but each time I create a new site I have to manually activate plugin and do a bulk-import.

Is there a way to set up Multisite to use Active Directory Integration (or any other sync method) site-wide instead of on each individual site?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Activate the plugin as a network plugin.

Go to **Network Admin/Plugins** (`wp-admin/network/plugins.php`), and activate it there. Before you do that, deactivate it on the single sites.